# Register new anonymous user with specific role through rest api in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-roles

I'm using Drupal 8 rest service to register a new anonymous user and it works fine; the user is created in Drupal.

Then I tried to specify a custom role sending the request below

```
{
    "name": { "value": "FooBar" },
    "mail": { "value": "foo@bar.com" },
    "pass": { "value": "secretSauce" },
    "roles": [
        "my_role"
    ]
}
```

but I receive the error

```
{
    "message": "Access denied on creating field 'roles'."
}
```

I checked permissions but I'm not getting what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An anonymous user cannot assign themselves a role. Drupal automatically assigns a user the role of 'Authenticated user'. You can alter the permissions of that role accordingly if that suits your needs.

*If you are using the excellent Simple oAuth module to authenticate, then you can also assign the user being created via the REST API a particular 'Scope' (role) based on the consumer ID used when creating the account. On your app you can then create the logic for the particular role to be assigned to a particular user.

*This all assumes that you are using a headless approach and the users are being created from a JS front-end.

**EDIT**

- Create custom field for Drupal Users
- Install the Rules Module (https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)
- Create a rule to act on a new user and assign the appropriate role per the value of the custom field.
- Pass in the desired value for the custom field from your front end (like your example above)

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I'm not getting how to assign the role. I'm using a headless approach where Drupal serves my js fe and I would like to assign a specific role (I have different roles) during the registration. I can create a new user invoking "localhost:8888/user/register?_format=json" and login invoking "localhost:8888/user/login?_format=hal_json". As you pointed the user is created with the role 'Authenticated user' and has no grants to assign a new role and from my fe layer I'm not getting how to orchestrate some logic without imagine some custom module

Comment: How many roles will you be using? Is there a specific criteria on who gets a particular one?

Comment: Ideally 3 initially will be 2; each role matches a value I would pass from the registration call. Imagine to select a value from the registration form and then convert this value into a specific role you are assigned to during the registration process. The registration is done from anonymous users, I'm using Drupal headless and I would like to avoid to create a custom module for this.

Comment: Updated answer above

Comment: I did it using rules

Answer (score 0):

I know that that's could very stupid but, actually I had the same mistake and the problem was that I send a GET request instead of POST

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).